# Microsecond support for VT_DATE type

Tags: vb6

Does VT_DATE variant type support microsecond resolution? Please let me know how to display the same in VB?

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221646.aspx:

> The variant time resolves to one second. Any milliseconds in the input date are ignored.